# Automatic Multi-level Sorting in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I currently have the following code that works and every time something is typed in, it is automatically sorted by column I

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    If Target.Column = 9 Then
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, 
               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 
        Range("A2:I" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("I2:I" & lastRow), 
              Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

    End If
End Sub
```

I want it so that it is primarily sorted by item I, but also secondarily sorted by column A. Any help please?

Comment: Wouldn't that be pretty annoying for whoever is entering the data?

Comment: It it sent to automatically sort after column 9 is entered so that is the last piece of data for the line, so doesn't really affect the user.  This is like a raw data sheet that automatically generates all the other sheets

Answer (score 2):

The starting point for any request like this should be "Fire up the macro recorder, perform a sort, and see what code it spits out".

If you fire up the recorder and add a multilevel sort like so:

[image]

[image]

...then the Macro Recorder spits out this:

```
Sub Macro11()
'
' Macro11 Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("I2:I16") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A16") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:I16")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

This gives you a clue as to the syntax you need to add multiple sort keys. Do you need help amending your original code, or is this enough to get you started?

Comment: I will look into this but it will definitely get me started, thank you!

Comment: Note that some of the stuff the Macro Recorder spits out is redundant. But when working out how to do stuff, the Macro Recorder is your friend.